# Determine whether a value is within the maximum range for that data type in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the correct way to determine if a number (in my case it is a value of power of two calculated by `pow(2,n)`) is within the limits of values that one variable type can take? I'm doing it like this: `if(pow (2,128)>std::numeric_limits<float>::max())`, but this is evaluated as `true` although it is expected that float's maximum value is 2^128 or something more. Is there any better way to do this comparison?

Comment: You cannot because to compare larger than the largest value it would have to *be* larger than the largest value. So depending on the numeric type, it will either overflow, or result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @CoryKramer -- it's not that simple. A `double` can (generally) hold a larger range of values than a `float`, so the comparison in the question is okay: `pow(2, 128)` returns a `double`, and the value on the RHS is promoted to `double` to match.

Comment: @PeteBecker Looking at [pow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) are you sure that the `double` is preferred when passing 2 integer literals?

Comment: @SombreroChicken -- yes.

Comment: The valid range for an exponent in an IEEE 754 single-precision value (which is what's typically used for `float`) is -126 to 127. It cannot represent 2^128, so the `true` result is correct. Nevertheless, this kind of question is fraught with complications, as @CoryKramer said.

Comment: Assuming `numeric_limits<double>::radix == 2`, you could always check that `n < numeric_limits<double>::max_exponent` to know that there won't be an overflow.

Comment: You can take the base 2 logarithm of the maximum limit and compare it to `n`.

Comment: @FeiXiang Please consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: @Bob__ It seems like the way the OP did it actually works pretty well though, except for 2^128, likely caused by floating point error. I think this is because float overflow results in `inf` at least on my machine (it's still undefined behavior).

Answer (score 2):

You can take the base 2 logarithm of the maximum limit for the type of variable and compare it to `n`. For example: `if(n > std::log2(std::numeric_limits<float>::max())`. You probably don't want `n` to be exactly on the limit though, since I think stuff like floating point error might cause some problems.

Answer (score 2):

For these kinds of limit checking, you can move the terms around to stay within the limits of the type.

In this case, `pow(2,n) == exp(ln(2)*n)` mathematically, so, rearranging terms, you can use `n > ln(maxval)/ln(2)`

Answer (score -2):

First of all can you answer what is the result of `pow(2, 128)`?
The real question is what is the type for this expression?

The second question is do you know how floating point numbers work?

Take a look on this code to give you a hints:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template<class T>
void printInfo(const std::string& desc, T x)
{
    std::cout << desc << ' ' << typeid(x).name() << ' ' << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    printInfo("A", std::pow(2, 128));
    printInfo("B", std::pow(2.0f, 128));
    printInfo("A", std::pow(2, 128.0f));
    auto c = std::pow(2.0f, 128.0f);
    printInfo("C", c);

    std::cout << (c > std::numeric_limits<float>::max()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (c == std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/bHdKqToDKdC0hSvW

I recommend review documentation of [numeric_limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/).
And analyze this code:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template<class T>
void print2exp()
{
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Radix          = " << std::numeric_limits<T>::radix << '\n';
    auto maxExp = std::numeric_limits<T>::max_exponent;
    std::cout << "Max exp        = " << maxExp  << '\n';
    std::cout << "2^maxExp       = " << std::pow(static_cast<T>(2), static_cast<T>(maxExp)) << '\n';
    std::cout << "2^(maxExp - 1) = " << std::pow(static_cast<T>(2), static_cast<T>(maxExp - 1)) << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    print2exp<float>();
    print2exp<double>();
    print2exp<long double>();

    return 0;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/J0hACKUKvKlV8lYK

So proper approach to this is (assuming that radix is 2):

```
if (x < std::numeric_limits<T>::max_exponent) {
    return std::pow(static_cast<T>(2), static_cast<T>(x));
} else {
    throw invalid_argument("x is to big to be use as 2^x");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: here is an improvement